# Full-screen, transparent, toggle-able terminal for Ubuntu? (Like Quake/Visor)

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, command-line, interface

I want to toggle a full-screen transparent terminal on some hotkey, so that when you close it, it just minimizes in the panel/tray but remains loaded in memory.

For example, Visor on Mac OS X:

[image]

Comment: [Guake](http://guake.org/), available in the repositories.

Comment: That's an answer, Chan-Ho, not a comment. This question will remain open unless you make it an answer (or someone else steals your comment to make it an answer, since I was going to recommend Guake too).

Comment: Someone did. Hahaha :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use [Guake](http://guake.org/screenshots)

- `sudo apt-get install guake`
- <kbd>F12</kbd> shows/hides
- Use Preferences to adjust opacity, height, shortcuts and much more...
- Guake on 12.04 Unity:

  [image]

Comment: thanks =) Before, I tried combine gnome terminal with alltray